# Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, following

I am investigating an issue with users cannot follow up site and looking at the logs I find the following error.

> Action: Follow a site
>   Error:
>   Something went wrong
>   Sorry, we couldn't follow the site.

TECHNICAL DETAILS

> SaveStoredPropertyForCurrentUser: failed to fetch property storage folder

Looking at ULS logs, SharePoint is looking for mysite in wrong Db and farm. and if we remove `SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer` then reconfigure it, it works for 15-20 minutes then stops working.

[ULS logs](http://1drv.ms/1kOWJBj)

http://1drv.ms/1kOWJBj

Comment: try to detach the content database(which hold all Mysite) and reattach it via pwoershell...check if it registered all site collections

Comment: Thank you for looking at this issue. I dismounted and mounted mysite content db then clicked on following a site but still I get this error in SharePoint site collection. Something went wrong
Sorry, we couldn't follow the site.
Technical Details
InternalError : Could not follow the item https://communities.mydomain.com/

Comment: and this one in ULS logs
ULS logs: http://1drv.ms/1nIN4a9
FollowedContent.get_FollowedSitesUrl() : Remote execution failed; Could not find followed sites url: Exception: Unexpected response from the server. The content type of the response is "text/html; charset=utf-8". The status code is "OK".